# Generar numero de registro

Tags: java, mysql

Amigos,
Estoy intentando generar un Numero de Registro autoincrementable con cierta estructura...
Los primeros dos numeros corresponden al año actual a eso se le agregan 000000 (5 ceros) y eso debe ir autoincrementando por cada registro que se vaya agregando... y ademas de eso al cumplir un nuevo año debe volver a cero y los dos primeros numero deben tambien cambiar...
QUEDANDO ASÍ: 1800001

Intenté hacerlo de manera arcaica y no me ha resultado, ya que va agregando el año nuevamente quedando en 18181800005

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yy"); 
String formattedDate = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());


        String sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(nregistro)+1 as nregistro 
FROM muestras ORDER BY nregistro DESC LIMIT 1";

        try {
            java.sql.Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                texto_registro = rs.getString("nregistro");
                System.out.println(" texto registro");
                if (texto_registro == null) {
                 //   lb_registro.repaint();
                    lb_registro.setText("000001");
                    lb_registro.repaint();
                }
            }if (year == ahora) {
                        lb_registro.setText(formattedDate + texto_registro);
                        System.out.println("registro");
                    } else {
                        lb_registro.setText(formattedDate + "000001");
                        lb_registro.repaint();
                    }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(Ladiox_Insertar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Parece que tu error se debe a que cuando consultas la base de datos para obtener tu último secuencial, ya estás trayendo "1800005" luego concatenas "18" al inicio. Podrías indicarnos la estructura, de la tabla que lees para obtener la secuencia, y unos ejemplos, si es la misma, entonces ese es tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: SÍ, me di cuenta que ese es uno de los errores... intenté concatenar pero al momento de hacer el insert efectivamente agrega nuevamente el 18... no se me ocurre como solucionar esa parte @Rostan

Comment: De que tipo es la columna "nregistro" en la tabla de muestras!?

Comment: Varchar @Rostan

Answer (score 1):

Ya que el inconveniente se presenta en la lectura del último registro, porque al obtenerlo estás devolviendo "1800005" cuando lo que deseas obtener sería 5, lo que puedes hacer es apoyarte en los casteos para hacer un substring de tu secuencia, algo así:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(nregistro, 2), INTEGER) + 1 as nregistro 
FROM muestras ORDER BY nregistro DESC LIMIT 1";
```

A la columna "nregistro" tipo caracter, le hago un substring a los dígitos que representan el secuencial (obteniendo '00004'), luego convierto lo obtenido en entero (obteniendo 4), y al final sumo el 1 (obteniendo 5).

Con ello en vez de obtener 1800005, obtengo el 5. ya con esto, depende de tí pasarlo nuevamente al formato que deseas cuando vayas a generar el insert. Saludos.

Comment: No me ha funcionado la consulta SQL

Comment: La consulta te devuelve algo? te salta algún mensaje de error?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT, SUBSTR(nregistro, 2)) + 1 as nregistro  FROM muestras WHERE laboratorioejec' at line 1

Comment: Son las palabras reservadas debido a tu motor de base de datos. Ya las actualicé por favor prueba y cuentanos.